# jQuery QuickFit resizes text not fitting into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text

I am using the [QuickFit library](https://github.com/chunksnbits/jquery-quickfit) to resize some text on my website.

But the text is bigger than the div with the fixed size.
I need to avoid that.

I use it like that:

```
   $(function() {

                    $(window).on('resize', function() {
                        $(".area_competences_text").quickfit({ max: 50, min: 10, truncate: false , tolerance: 0.08});        
                    });

           $(window).trigger('resize'); 

        });
```

gives that result: 
[image]

my HTML:

```
 <div class ="cell cell2">
               <table class="layoutTable"><tr><td class="centerDiv">
                      <div class="area_competences_text text_software"> 
                          <div class="referencesProductHeader">            
                            SOFTWARE- UND DATENBANKENTWICKLUNG <br>
                          </div>
                                <ul class="listStyle">
                                   <li> Analyse der Geschäftsprozesse</li>
                                   <li> Entwicklung von Lösungskonzepten und Priorisierung der Anforderungen</li>
                                   <li> Entwicklung einer Client/Server Anwendung</li>
                                   <li> Schwerpunkt: Logistikabwicklung im Umfeld einer Nicht-Serienfertigung</li>
                                   <li> Rollout in Deutschland, Österreich, China und auf Baustellen weltweit</li>
                                   <li> Projektbegleitende Beratung und Moderation</li>
                                   <li> Wartung und Support international</li>
                                   <li> Technologien: Client/Server, Webanwendung <br> und mobile Barcodescanner-Lösung</li>  
                                </ul>  

                                </div>
                </td></tr></table>
          </div>
```

Why is it overlapping its div with a fixed size?

Comment: Do you have a example where it fails?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my post

Answer (score 0):

`width: 20` <-- You are saying to be 20 pixels wide. Remove it.

```js
 $(function() {

   $(window).on('resize', function() {
     $(".area_competences_text1").quickfit({
       max: 50,
       min: 10,
       truncate: false,
       tolerance: 0.08,
       width: 20
     });
     

    $(".area_competences_text2").quickfit({
       max: 50,
       min: 10,
       truncate: false,
       tolerance: 0.08
     });
   });

   $(window).trigger('resize');

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/chunksnbits/jquery-quickfit/master/jquery.quickfit.js"></script>

<div class="area_competences_text1">with Width</div>
<div class="area_competences_text2">without Width</div>
```

Comment: added html to my post. do you need the css?